# React post image file upload issue - Production only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to attach an image file. Somehow my client side didnt send anything if attaching a file there.

It's on React(website) and React-Native Web View(rendering).

Bad part of the game is, I cant track the client log, cause of mobile browser issue.

**1)**

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('report[description]', text);
formData.append('token', localStorage.getItem('tempToken'));
formData.append('report[image]', new Blob([this.state.file], { type: 'image/png' }));
axios.post('/accept_report', formData)
```

**2)**

```
const config = {
   headers: {
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
   }
}
formData.append('report[image]', this.state.file);
axios.post("/accept_report", formData, config)
```

Comment: so what errors are you getting?

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Actually nothing, since from browser i can see the log and works properly. But on mobile i cant see logs and not even request to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

Since, It happens only when attaching the file. My Production `nginx` was restricting big sized files. I was only able to upload around 500kb not over.

Have changed `nginx` client body size.

```
http{
   #...
   client_max_body_size 10M; #or 100M it depends on yr preference.
   #...
}
```